# Coefficient output in R for full model

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

I am having trouble understanding what exactly R is outputting when I look at the coefficient summary for the full model.

For the lowbwt data, there are 4 variables: low, age, lwt, race (3 levels), and ftv. Low is the binary response variable.

For example, if I am testing H0: beta_lwt=0 vs H1: beta_lwt=/=0, why don't I get the same estimates for lwt under h1 and m1?

What is exactly is the difference between testing
H0: beta_lwt = 0 vs H1: beta_lwt =/= 0
and testing
M0: beta_age=beta_race=beta_ftv=0 vs M1: beta_age=beta_lwt=beta_race=beta_ftv=0?

```
> h1 <- glm(low ~ lwt, family=binomial, data=lowbwt)
> summary(h1)$coef
             Estimate  Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.99831432 0.785290874  1.271267 0.20363370
**lwt         -0.01405826 0.006169588 -2.278639 0.02268856**
> m1 <- glm(low ~ age + lwt + race + ftv, family=binomial, data=lowbwt)
> summary(m1)$coef
               Estimate  Std. Error    z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  1.29536575 1.071443130  1.2089916 0.22666607
age         -0.02382297 0.033729620 -0.7062924 0.48000632
**lwt         -0.01424461 0.006540719 -2.1778358 0.02941826**
race2        1.00389782 0.497858958  2.0164302 0.04375501
race3        0.43310843 0.362240236  1.1956387 0.23183760
ftv         -0.04930832 0.167239083 -0.2948373 0.76811818
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The estimates for the effect of `lmt` differ due to the different variables included in `h1` and `m1`. In `h1`, `lwt` the only predictor, whereas `m1` additionally includes the continuous variables `age` and `fvt` and the categorial varible `race`. Since all predictor variables are used in the fitting procedure, the estimates for one variable depend on the presence/absence of other variables.

In your example, the difference between both models most likely is primarily caused by the factor `race`, which has three levels. If no contrast is specified in R, treatment contrasts are applied to categorial variables. This is the default in R. Hence, in the model `m1` the first level of `race` (probably `1`) is used as reference category. The effects of both `race2` and `race3` are estimated relative to the first level of `race`.

The treatment contrast coding has implications for all other effects in the model. These effects are estimated for the reference category only. Due to this, the intercept, `age`, `lwt`, and `fvt` only hold for the first level of `race` in model `m1`. In contrast, the factor `race` is absent in model `h1` and thereby both the intercept and the effect of `lwt` are estimated for all levels of `race`.

To sum up, only model `h1` does test wether there is a general effect of `lwt`. With model `m1`, you can only test the effect of `lwt` on the subset of data where `race` is `1`.